# When RelativeLayout is into a ScrollView, moving TextView with touch doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, android, touch

In my app, I create a `TextView` programmatically and user can moves it with touch. This is my `MainActivity` code:

```
    rleEditImage= (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.rleEditImage);

    TextView newTextView = new TextView(G.context);
    newTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    newTextView.setText("TextView");
    newTextView.setId(2);
    newTextView.setTextSize(26);
    rleEditImage.addView(newTextView);
    final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(2);
    txt.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
            final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;
            }
            rleEditImage.invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

And this is my `.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#dfdfdf"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/srlCreate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
     >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rleEditImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But it's not work correctly. When I remove `ScrollView` it will works correctly. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use `AbsoluteLayout` Instead Of `RelativeLayout`.
`AbsoluteLayout` Will Provide More Free Movement for The `TextView`